# Oracle - convert a value to 0 after INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table called Army.There are the attributes:

**army**

- army_name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
- number_of_soliders INTEGER;

I need to convert number_of_soliders to 0 after inserting to this table (or allow only 0 to be inserted).

How to accomplish this?

Comment: As an aside, soldiers has the "i" after the "d".

Comment: Oh thanks I'm not a native speaker and some of the english words are tricky :P

Answer (score 0):

Since this is [part of a school project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70229155/trigger-in-oracle-increment-column-referenced-with-foreign-key#comment124147157_70229609), you need to use a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement and modify the value `BEFORE INSERT ON army` and do that `FOR EACH ROW`.

In the trigger's PL/SQL block, you need to use the `:new` record and set the `number_of_soldiers` attribute to be zero using `:NEW.number_of_soldiers := 0;`.

The documentation for `CREATE TRIGGER` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html).

Comment: Well, I tried this: 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_SOLIDER_NUMBER
AFTER INSERT ON army
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE army
SET number_of_soliders = 0 WHERE army_name = :new.army_name;
END;

but i keep getting error: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it, and error on line two. I also tried this:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_SOLIDER_NUMBER
BEFORE INSERT ON army
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE army
SET :new.number_of_soliders := 0;
END;

but this has a wrong syntax according to SQL developer

Comment: Do **NOT** use an `UPDATE` statement. As I said in the answer, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and then just use the PL/SQL statement `:NEW.number_of_soldiers := 0;` and nothing else in the PL/SQL block.

Comment: My god I finally got it! Thanks a lot, I owe you a beer, haha

Answer (score -1):

You can try altering the column and set default value as `0`.

So, when you insert `army_name`, the row will by default have `number_of_soliders` as `0`.

```
ALTER TABLE ARMY MODIFY number_of_soliders default 0;
```

Comment: From 12c onwards `default on null` prevents nulls being explicitly entered. However, the OP's unusual requirement here is that all values entered should be replaced with 0, not just nulls.